# How do I obtain an intermediate solution using the pydrake interface to Gurobi

Tags: python, drake

I'm using pydrake to interface with Gurobi and solve a second-order cone program. I am hoping to get the solution at each iterate so I can see how the solution evolves.

Whenever termination is due to number of iterates, the early termination appears to return the variable solutions as NaNs, regardless of the number of iterates.

The result info is as follows: `result.get_solution_result() == SolutionResult.kUnknownError` and `result.is_success() == False`

Inspection of the GurobiSolverDetails shows the following:

- error_code: 0
- optimizer_time: 0.05 (or some other float depending on the problem)
- objective_bound: NaN
- optimization_status: 7

Other hopefully relevant info:

- Drake/pydrake (built from source, most recent commit on main branch `42448c0`)
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Gurobi 9.5.1

I was originally working with Ubuntu 18.04 and Gurobi 9.1

I thought that updating to latest version of things might fix these issues but it seems I'm getting identical solutions. My back up plan is to just implement this in `gurobipy` without using Drake at all but would prefer to see if that's avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the "debug mathematical program" tutorial?  https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/notebook/debug_mathematical_program-9acce39e5eb642e392d86d0809fa5c76
In particular, for gurobi we often turn on the solver verbosity.

There are also some gurobi-specific solution results available via https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/structdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_gurobi_solver_details.html

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged; see [When is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/1247191)

Comment: I think my answer is an answer according to that post.  It has useful information besides the link.  ;-)

Comment: the majority of the answer is a link (or two links). Please incorporate some information and/or code samples into your answer.

Comment: Hey Russ, unfortunately I've tried out both the debug mathematical program tutorial and tried to access the gurobi-specific contents (see info in original post on the GurobiSolverDetails). It seems like, for whatever reason, when terminating due to number of iterations (but not other conditions) Drake is having trouble handling the solution. I suspect it's just not handling the iterationTermination case, so maybe is a simple fix. Time permitting, I might try to look at the source code and see what's going on so I can provide more useful feedback :-)

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  I looked at the code, and agree that our interface should definitely handle those exit codes better.  I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18366

If you're willing to contribute a fix, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Good news.  The amazing Hongkai Dai has already PR'd a fix.  It should land in Drake soon.